# C++ Question about memory not too complicated

Tags: c++

When I create a character like:

`char anything = 'x';`

This takes up 8 bits in memory, and it's bit pattern will probably look something like `01111000`.

Now, my question is, how does the computer know exactly that this is a character?

And another question, is the character `'x'` really ever written anywhere? Or does the computer just turn it into binary for memory, and then when I want to use the variable for anything, it just turns that binary back into the character `x`?

Comment: Perhaps of relevance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

Comment: This is very wide topic to answer, and doesn't have to do with C++ directly. Remember: the computer _knows_ nothing. Everything is in bits, always.

Comment: Unspecified by the C++ Standard exactly where it goes, but in the case of a small literal like 'x' all that likely exists is an instruction that stores 120, the ascii code (assuming ascii) code for 'x', into a variable. example: https://godbolt.org/z/5799bM8TP . A larger string will be stored in a read-only data section of the program.

Comment: `Computer` knows nothing, it lacks cognitive skills. Programmer does, and uses this knowledge to do something meaningful with this value.

Comment: The type `char` tells the compiler to treat the contents of `anything` as a character.  Single quotes around `x` tells the compiler that `x` is a character literal.  The compiler has tables that map character literals to *binary* values.  This tables are used when converting characters to internal representation (e.g. binary).

Answer (score 1):

> how does the computer know exactly that this is a character?

It doesn't.  As far as the computer is concerned, it is just an arbitrary number in memory (in this case, decimal 120). Only your code gives any meaning to what that number represents.

> is the character `'x'` really ever written anywhere?

No.  It is just a human-readable representation of that number.

> Or does the computer just turn it into binary for memory, and then when I want to use the variable for anything, it just turns that binary back into the character `x`?

Like I said, it is just a number in memory, nothing more.  When you read the value and *interpret* it as a particular data type, then that number has meaning for that type.  For instance, if you read the number 120 into a `char`, it represents the character `'x'`.  If you read that same number 120 into an `int8_t` (or larger), it represents an integer 120.  If you read that same number 120 into a byte holding a bitmask, it represents a set of flags with bits 3-6 turned on and bits 0-2 and 7 turned off.  And so on.

Comment: Wait why 120? Shouldn't it be like 01111000 because that's the bit pattern? Or idk I'm confused now

Comment: @yaelreshet11 decimal 120, hex 0x78, octal 170, binary 01111000, they are all just different representations of the same numeric value

Comment: So all those are like the bit pattern? And well so basically the bit pattern is the value right? And sorry for asking so many questions but does the memory know 01111000 refers to the variable anything? Like does it somehow know hey there's this variable called anything and it's bit pattern in binary is 01111000? But again I'm still kinda confused like where exactly the value is stored like I say char anything = 'x'; this takes up 8 bits in memory and has a bit pattern of 01111000 so is it just okay to say that 01111000 is the value?

Comment: Remember all of the change of base stuff you covered in Math class at some point? Where you had to take numbers represented in base 10 and turn them into number in base 5? This is one of the places where that pays off. That bit pattern is a number in base 2. People got tired of typing all the ones and zeroes long, long ago and started using base 8, base 10, and base 16 to represent the same number. 01111000, 170, 120, and 78 are all the same number, just interpreted in different bases, specifically 2(binary), 8 (octal), 10 (decimal), and 16 (hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

> Now, my question is, how does the computer know exactly that this is a character?

Most compiler either use utf8 as encoding. Some may use ascii too, and other encoding also exist.

As utf8 and ascii says, the value of `x` is `120` (decimal). The bit pattern of `x` or in this case `120` will be what the variable `anything` will contain.

The very same happen if you do this:

```
char anything = 120;
```

The very same value would be written in memory (if not folded away) and printing `anything` to the console will give you back `x`.

> And another question, is the character 'x' really ever written anywhere?

Do you mean is the text `'x'` written anywhere in the compiled binary? Well technically yes, if you compiled an unoptimized build you may see that the assembly code will push `120` in a register. That `120` is `x`. If you were to dump the binary into a file and try to read it as ascii, you might see an `x` popping up. Reading it as hex you will see `78` appearing. The letter `x` is just a way to interpret the number `120`.